# How do I stop a location.href from executing on a minified javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect, minify

I have this minified javascript file that I can't block from loading on the page, and there's a function on that minified script that I wanna stop from running, and since that function gets loaded on the page and I have no control over it I have to find a way to stop it after it gets loaded, can't just simply remove the javascript function from the minified file.

**This is the minified function (after beautify) that I wanna stop :**

```
    function _(t, e) {
        var n = e.getState(),
            r = f.get(t, "order.account.status");
        r === u.USER_STATES.SCHOOL_USER_LOGGED_IN && a.checkoutTracker.identity.loginSuccessful();
        var o = f.get(t, "redirect_to");
        if (o) location.href = o;
        else if (r === u.USER_STATES.LOCKED) f.get(n, "ui.htmlForms.login-school").showError(l);
        else if (r.indexOf(u.USER_STATES.LOGGED_OUT_SUBSTR) > -1) f.get(n, "ui.htmlForms.login-school").showError();
        else {
            var i = t.order;
            ! function(t) {
                var e = t.getState();
                f.get(e, "ui.elements.$alertMyTeachable").classList.add("hidden"), f.get(e, "ui.htmlForms.email.$form").classList.add("hidden")
            }(e), i && e.dispatch(s.receiveOrderUpdate(i))
        }
    }
```

So basically what that function does is it gets the value of the field `"redirect_to"` from a json file and then uses a `location.href` to redirect to that value (that value is an url). You can see this happening on the 5th and 6th line.

What I wanna do is to stop it from redirecting, since its a minified javascript file there's no way to find out the name of the function and replace it by an empty function with the same name after the minified file gets loaded on the page, I also tried using `Object.freeze(document.location);` this method works on Chrome but it's not supported on browsers like Safari and Firefox.
So I need a way to stop that location.href from getting triggered so I can support all browsers and I have no idea how.

I hope anyone can help, I've been trying to figure this out for days.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: where does this function gets invoked ?

Comment: Does this file stays constant or name mangling happens with every new build ?

Comment: @AdityaBhave I'm sure it stays constant but it's still a minified javascript, is there any way to even find out the actual name of the function?

Comment: Well, I searched the whole file for "USER_STATES.SCHOOL_USER_LOGGED_IN" and found only 2 instances. The search string is present in your function. So this tells you exact location. If you can, just update this file directly.

Comment: @AdityaBhave Can you explain a bit more? I'm a bit slow, is "USER_STATES.SCHOOL_USER_LOGGED_IN" a value? how does it affect the redirect and how do you think I can change it to stop the redirect? also I can't change the file directly otherwise I would just remove the location.href  and also this is the json file that the function gets the value from {"redirect_to":"/secure/470176/checkout/1574051/advanced-product-research/password","completed_order":true} I don't know if that's of any help

Comment: Ahh, Sorry. I thought you can change the file.

Comment: You can't override `window.location.href` with `null`? Then set it back after the redirecting attempt.